# Proper way to keep array from pipe BASH

Tags: arrays, bash, pipe

I saw quite a few different solutions to resolve an issue with keeping an array from a pipe however none seemed to do the trick for me, currently my script works correctly however the array "databasesarray" is lost upon "done", how would I go about keeping this information with my complex pipe scheme?

```
databasesarray=()
N=0

dbs -d 123123 | grep db|awk '{print $2}'|while read db;
do
    databasesarray[$N]="$db";
    databasesarray[$N]+=$(gdb $db|grep dn);
    echo ${N} ${databasesarray[$N]};
    N=$(($N + 1));
done
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better and more efficient way of filling up array in a loop:

```
databasesarray=()

while read -r db; do
    databasesarray+=( "$db $(gdb "$db"|grep "dn")" )
done < <(dbs -d 123123 | awk '/db/{print $2}')
```

- Your grep and awk can be combined into one
- Instead of pipe with while it better to use process substitution `< <(...)` syntax

PS: You could use `read -a` for filling up array:

```
read -a databasesarray < <(dbs -d 123123 | awk '/db/{print $2}')
```

Comment: Thank you for this! however after "$db:" $(gdb "$db"|grep "dn") it does not appear to print out what $(gdb "$db"|grep "dn") would print out

Comment: Think you're on right track, output I get is: [0]fqdn [1]= [2]www.example.com, seems now $db is left out and it's assigning to each word of output from gdb grep command

Comment: @0n35: The whole command substitution should be double-quoted to prevent word splitting when adding to the array; you can prepend `$db` in there: `"$db $(gdb "$db"|grep "dn")"`.

Comment: @anubhava: You're welcome; another thing (just updated my comment): the OP wants `"$db"` prepended to the new array item.

Comment: @mklement0: Actually I had `"$db"` before but due to 1st comment from OP removed it. I can add it again but wasn't sure if OP wants it that way.